# How to have Vim recognize the object type when accessing an STL container, for autocompletion

Tags: c++, vim, stl, autocomplete

I have the omnicppcomplete plugin with exuberant ctags, I generate tags for projects with the following command:

```
ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have Vim recognize the type of an object when I access it through an STL container, to provide me with an appropriate list of autocomplete suggestions.

For example suppose the `IntWrapper` object has a `getTheInt()` method and I have a vector of `IntWrappers`:

```
std::vector<IntWrapper> wrappers;
```

If I have the following code:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < wrappers.size(); i++) {
    wrappers[i].<VIM Cursor is here>
}
```

I'd like VIM to understand that wrapper[i] is of type `IntWrapper` and to give me the `getTheInt()` method as the first autocompletion choice, along with documentation, as if I operated on an IntWrappers object directly.

To make clear what I would expect, the first screenshot below is what happens when I ask for autocompletion on the vector, the second one is what happens when I access the object directly, and what I'd like to achieve even with stl containers.

[image: Expression not found]

(The sentence highlighted in red above says **expression not found**)

[image: Working]

Is there any plugin (I don't care about CPU expensiveness) to do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: have you tried otu clang_complete?

Comment: @PlasmaHH no, I never did! More details about it are welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, I think that omnicomplete can't deal with context issue, so you can't use it for your purpose. A way to do C++/STL auto-completion is to use [clang_complete](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete) (or [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302)).

The performance seems to be quite problematic though (Have a look here : [How to improve the completion speed of clang_complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887831/how-to-improve-the-completion-speed-of-clang-complete) ).

A nice tutorial on the subject (configure vim + clang for C++ STL completion) could be found here : http://zwiener.org/vimautocomplete.html

Ref:

- C++98 and C++11 Support in Clang : http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html
- Vim Clang_complete documentation : https://github.com/krisajenkins/clang_complete/blob/master/doc/clang_complete.txt

NB : Another option is to use gccsense which is a stand alone tool using GCC's code analyzers. Here is the link to the project homepage : http://cx4a.org/software/gccsense/
and on two SO questions about its use :

- [gccsense vs. clang_complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454803/gccsense-vs-clang-complete)
- [Is there an alternative to ctags that works better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748454/is-there-an-alternative-to-ctags-that-works-better)

Comment: `clang_complete` uses the python bindings and there is a lot of work ongoing on them, for anyone planning to use them I suggest keeping close to the trunk version.